# Android; Type com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy is defined multiple times:

Tags: android

after importing a project library i get the error

C:\Users\Jordy\AndroidStudioProjects\Application\app\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\debug\out\classes.dex

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Same for me after upgrading to gradle plugin 4.0.0, but for `moxy.MvpView$$State` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just had this problem again, i did solve it this time.

open your android project in explorer, delete the `.gradle` folder
then go to the `app` folder and delete the `build`folder in there.

re-run your project in android studio and it should be fixed